# How to deal with dynamic combobox while using dictionary to store the textvariable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter, combobox

I'm making a APP with Python, and plan to generate multiple dropdown button respect to the input number from user. I'm using dict type to store the result of every dropdown button. However the get(key) method in the dict type can not get the value of the combobox. Can anyone help me with this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

I'm using python 3.6 and tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

listA=["s1","s2"]
def Readstatus(event,key):
    print(root.var.get(key))

def data():
    root.var = dict()
    for i in range(2):

       root.var[i]=tk.StringVar()
       tk.Label(frame,text=i).grid(row=i,column=0)
       tk.Label(frame,text="my text"+str(i)).grid(row=i,column=1)
       frame.cb=ttk.Combobox(frame,values=listA, textvariable=root.var[i])
       frame.cb.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",lambda event,key=i: Readstatus(event,key))
       frame.cb.grid(row=i, column=2)
def myfunction(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=780,height=150)
root=tk.Tk()
sizex = 820
sizey = 600
posx  = 100
posy  = 100
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

myframe=tk.Frame(root,relief=tk.GROOVE,width=800,height=150,bd=1)
myframe.place(x=10,y=400)

canvas=tk.Canvas(myframe)
frame=tk.Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(myframe,orient="vertical",command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)

myscrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.create_window((0,0),window=frame,anchor='nw')
frame.bind("<Configure>",myfunction)
data()
root.mainloop()
```

I expect, for example, have 2 dropdown button and the selected result will be stored in root.var, like {'0':'S1','1':'S2'}. However, the root.var is {0: , 1: }. It seems the get() method does not work.

Comment: Do you mean you want to retrieve the value of your `StringVar` when you select the combobox? Right now it prints out the reference of the `StringVar`. Just put `print(root.var.get(key).get())` to get its value

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. It solved my issue@HenryYik